# How to read character-valued parameters set in YAML header as column names after applying pivot_wider?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyr

I'm trying to develop an R-markdown report where I can set the parameters as the current and previous quarters as shown in the example. Part of the report involves pivoting these strings into column names and then calculating a percent change. However, the mutate() call is evaluating the params$ as the string values I set to them rather than column names they've been pivoted to. Is there a trick to either make mutate() evaluate the parameter value as column names, or set the parameter to something different so that the code will work as written?

```
---
title: "my_notebook"
output: html_notebook
params:
  this_qtr: "2020Q2"
  last_qtr: "2020Q1"
---
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble::tibble(quarter = c(rep(params$this_qtr, 4), rep(params$last_qtr, 4)),
                       amount = rnorm(8),
                       state = rep(c("pa", "nj", "md", "de"), 2))

data_wide <- data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = quarter, values_from = amount)

# throws an error because params$ are character strings rather than column names
data_pct_ch <- data_wide %>% mutate(pct_ch = params$this_qtr/params$last_qtr - 1)
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove params$?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the string version of the `params` values into symbols. You can do that with `rlang::sym` and then inject that into the mutate with `!!`. Try

```
data_pct_ch <- data_wide %>% 
  mutate(pct_ch = !!rlang::sym(params$this_qtr)/!!rlang::sym(params$last_qtr) - 1)
```

Or you can use character indexing with the `.data` pronoun

```
data_pct_ch <- data_wide %>% 
  mutate(pct_ch = .data[[params$this_qtr]]/.data[[params$last_qtr]] - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work for me. I am a little confused why the !! are necessary though, since it seems the sym() function already takes care of converting the quoted string to a name.